# Why does this code result in a NPE while sleeping to avoid rate limit in Twitter4J?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, rate-limiting

I am using Twitter4j to fetch the followers of a given user. At some point I always hit the rate limit. I am happy for the program to sleep for 15 minutes to over come this. However when it wakes, I get an error.

See the following code:

```
protected IDs fetchAndStoreFollowers(TwitterUser user) {
    Twitter twitter = this.getTwitterApi();
    long cursor = -1;
    IDs ids = null;
    do {
        try {
            ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(user.getId(), cursor);
            System.out.println("Got a followers batch");
            cursor = ids.getNextCursor();
            this.storeFollowers(user, ids);
            System.out.println("Saved!");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            System.out.println("Oh no! Rate limit exceeded... going to sleep.");
            handleTwitterException(e);
            System.out.println("Waking up!");
        }
    } while (ids.hasNext());
    return ids;
}
```

After waking up from the sleep the program throws a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
} while (ids.hasNext());
```

Can anybody spot why?

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the encountered error is reproducible and quite logic.

First, you initialize your `ids` to `null`.

In case a `RateLimitException` (TwitterException) occurs, no actual value is ever set to the variable `ids` in the line with:

```
ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(user.getId(), cursor);
```

The code in the `catch`-Block is then executed - while `ids` is still pointing to `null`. After this is processed (and you see output on your console...), the line:

```
while (ids.hasNext());
```

produces the `NullPointerException`.

### Solution

Change the while-condition as follows:

```
while (ids == null || (id!=null && ids.hasNext()));
```

Be aware that the value in `cursor` might not have been or has to be changed accordingly, in case of an error situation.

Hope this helps.